# XML to JSON using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an XML that is not well formatted but needs to be consumed:

```
<Users>
<User First="aaa" Second="bbb">InnerValue</User>
<User First="bbb" Second="">InnerValue</User>
</Users>
```

Clases definitions:

```
public class Users
    {            
        public List<User> User{ get; set; }
    }

 public class User
    {        
        [JsonProperty("@First")]
        public string First{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("@Second")]
        public string Second{ get; set; }

        //how to define a property to get the InnerValue
    }
```

To parse:

```
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xmlDocument);
Users users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(jsonData);
```

So everything is nicely deserialized but how to get the inner value?

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can't get the InnerValue as i have explained.

Comment: hey @plurby any special reason to use Json.net ?

Comment: @BaljeetsinghSucharia It's a requirement.

Comment: hmm ok got - but if not json i hope you know that this can also be useful var usersList = from s in xml.Descendants("Users")                                 select s; - loop through each userItem - each userItem can give you value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the inner value you must use  `[JsonProperty("#text")]` so to update:

```
public class User
    {        
        [JsonProperty("@First")]
        public string First{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("@Second")]
        public string Second{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("#text")]
        public string InnerValue { get; set; }
    }
```